# Single Validation function, called once per Animation function

Tags: javascript, validation

Just looking for a way to include a single validation function *inside* of another function, that will stop any other lines from executing if it fails.

NOT an if statement... I'm trying to avoid nesting, because.. idk, I want to try to avoid it as much as possible.

So.... Is it bad to throw an Error to do this? I can't use return because it only ends the checkAnimationState(); but it doesn't also break out of the moveBlock() function...

**[JS FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/mky4115a/2/)**

```
$(function(){
    // cache dom 
    var $button = $('#button');
    var $block = $('#block');

    // event handlers 
    $button.on('click', moveBlock);

    // functions
    function checkAnimationState(){
      if(!$block.hasClass('animating')){
        $block.addClass('animating');
      } else {
        throw Error('Block is already animating... BE PATIENT.');
      }
    }

  function moveBlock(){
    checkAnimationState(); // prevent animation if already animating.. validation.. 
    $block.animate(
        {marginLeft:'400px'},
      {
        duration: 3000,
        easing: "linear",
        complete: function(){
            $block.removeAttr('style').removeClass('animating');
        }
      }
    ); // end .animate();
  }
});
```

Comment: `!isAnimationRunning() && $block.animate(...` No `if`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some possibilities:

**1.** If you wanna `throw` and error it's advised to use [try...catch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch) to handle the error, also this way the action the user's done will be executed when the condition is matched (when the block is finished animating) if you use `finally`. [try...catch...finally DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/mky4115a/3/)

```
$(function(){
  // cache dom 
    var $button = $('#button');
  var $block = $('#block');

  // event handlers 
    $button.on('click', moveBlock);

  // functions
    function checkAnimationState(){
    if(!$block.hasClass('animating')){
        $block.addClass('animating');
    } else {
        throw Error('Block is already animating... BE PATIENT.');
    }
  }

  function moveBlock(){
    try{
        checkAnimationState(); // check for animation - essentially validation
    }
    catch(e){
        console.log(e);
        return false;
    }
    finally{
      $block.animate(
        {marginLeft:'400px'},
        {
          duration: 3000,
          easing: "linear",
          complete: function(){
            $block.removeAttr('style').removeClass('animating');
          }
        }
      )
    }
  }
});
```

**2.** You can use `callback` inside your `checkAnimationState()` function to execute or pass the animation command: [callback DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/mky4115a/4/)

```
$(function(){
  // cache dom 
    var $button = $('#button');
  var $block = $('#block');

  // event handlers 
    $button.on('click', moveBlock);

  // functions
    function checkAnimationState(callback){
    if(!$block.hasClass('animating')){
        $block.addClass('animating');
      callback();
    }
  }

  function moveBlock(){
    checkAnimationState(function(){
      $block.animate(
        {marginLeft:'400px'},
        {
          duration: 3000,
          easing: "linear",
          complete: function(){
            $block.removeAttr('style').removeClass('animating');
          }
        }
      )
    }); // check for animation - essentially validation
  }
});
```

**3.** You can have your `checkAnimationState()` function return a value wether the condition is matched or not and use an `if(...)` statement. *(I know this one is probably not what the OP wants, but I just wanted to mention it for other people who may stumble upon this question)* [if (...) DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/mky4115a/5/)

```
$(function(){
  // cache dom 
    var $button = $('#button');
  var $block = $('#block');

  // event handlers 
    $button.on('click', moveBlock);

  // functions
    function checkAnimationState(){
      var isAnimating = !$block.hasClass('animating');
    $block.addClass('animating'); //since jQuery wont add an existing class, no need to check for it's existance before adding
    return isAnimating;
  }

  function moveBlock(){
    if(checkAnimationState()){ // check for animation - essentially validation
      $block.animate(
        {marginLeft:'400px'},
        {
          duration: 3000,
          easing: "linear",
          complete: function(){
            $block.removeAttr('style').removeClass('animating');
          }
        }
      )
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Well done! I have used option 3 before, but I think option 2 look the cleanest and I might pursue that one. Option 1 is kind of like what I am doing, but the proper way to do (_the way you did it_), looks so chunky, i don't like it. 

Thanks for the advice!

Comment: you're welcome, just remember in different situations different approaches may be required! BTW my favorite is option 2 too :)